# Changing theme of whole application in Application class

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I tried to change the theme dynamically in whole app by using **setTheme** in **onCreate** of **Application** class. But it does not load theme.
I know I can set theme in each individual activity, but I need to set theme once in application class and let coming activities inflate using application theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this before too, the only solution I found was declaring a global variable that stores what theme is selected so you can set the theme in the onCreate of every Activity.

Comment: Yes, seems this is the only solution.

Comment: Make all activities to use custom base class and put there code to set theme.